# Map one stream to another stream and close the first when the second closes

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, java-8, java-stream

I have a log file, each of whose lines I want to use to create a `LogMessage` object. I want to stream the lines from the file, and map each one to a new `LogMessage`. The code below works, but Eclipse issues a warning:

> Resource leak: 'lineStream' is never closed

```
public static Stream<LogMessage> streamSingleLineLogMessages(Path path) {
    try {
        Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        Stream<LogMessage> logMessageStream =
                lineStream.map(message -> new LogMessage(path, message));
        logMessageStream.onClose(lineStream::close);
        return logMessageStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If I add a `finally` block, and close it in there, then the stream is closed when the method returns (I think). In any case, it is closed by the time I come to use it.

So what it is the best way to ensure that the inner stream is closed? Or perhaps the code is correct as it is, but Eclipse doesn't realize it?

Comment: It turns out the resource leak analysis hasn't yet been updated for Java 8 method references. I filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/486506

Comment: After a long wait, starting with tomorrows integration build Eclipse will only report a potential resource leak (local analysis still can't make a definite call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually shouldn't need any of this and have instead:

```
public static Stream<LogMessage> streamSingleLineLogMessages(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
                .map(message -> new LogMessage(path, message));
}
```

The method [`Files.lines(path, cs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) returns a `Stream<Path>` that already has a close handler closing the internal `BufferedReader`. When this Stream is mapped to a `Stream<LogMessage>`, the close handlers are kept.

This means that for the new `Stream<LogMessage>`, there is already a close handler closing the `BufferedReader`, so you don't need to add it yourself.

You just need to make sure that when you use this method, you wrap it property inside a `try-with-resources` construct:

```
try (Stream<LogMessage> messageStream = streamSingleLineLogMessages(path)) {
    // do something with the stream
}
```

Comment: I'm using `streamSingleLineLogMessages` as a lambda function. So it can't throw checked exceptions.

Comment: @whistling_marmot `streamSingleLineLogMessages` will throw an `IOException` if `Files.lines` throw an exception.

Comment: However, inlining the `lineStream` (as in your code) makes the eclipse warning disappear, even when I keep the try-catch.